# can not log in to prestashop store admin(back office)

Tags: prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.7. I tried to log in to the store admin, but it prevented me while showing the following errors.

1.Error found: CData section not finished https://addons.prestashop.com/en/analytics-statist in country_module_list.xml file.

2.Error found: EndTag: '

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go in **/config/xml/**
and delete existing *country_module_list.xml* file
as it probably got corrupted during download from
Prestashop servers (or maybe you run out of disk space during download
so check this also).

The file will be downloaded again on next access.